# Detect Windows OS only by registry

Tags: windows, registry

I'm looking for a way to detect windows OS **only** by checking the registry.
By windows OS I mean Win10, Win11, Server 2012, Server 2016, Sever 2019 and Server 2022.
It seems some registry values under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion remain the same, for example the CurrentMajorVersionNumber and CurrentMinorVersionNumber are the same for Win10 and Server 2016.
So is there a reliable way to get this info ?

Comment: Does the "EditionID" or "InstallationType" from that same registry paths give a hint of "server" vs" "client"? However, given that the registry isn't documented and could change in a future update, let me ask: **What are you really trying to do?** by having code that detects an OS SKU?  What behavior in your product will change based on OS type? (There are legit reasons - but 99% the version check alone is all you need). Or is it just for logging? Why not use the supported APIs? Why is it critical to distinguish between client and server SKUs?

Comment: @selbie EditionID is too special, 100 different values.

Comment: No, there's no way to do that via the registry alone. There's an API for getting the Windows version.

Answer (score 0):

`InstallationType` might be usable but I don't know how far back it goes. All the values under Windows NT\CurrentVersion are undocumented but they will tell you the real version. All you really need to know is the build number, server/client, and for < Win10, the service pack.

The classic client/server value to check is `ProductType` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ProductOptions`. `WinNT` means client OS.